# VB: Help fixing a listbox issue

Tags: vb.net

So I have created a bot, and for some reason with the proxy scraper I made it show all proxies on the one line within ListBox2. I need it to show one proxy per line, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.socialstamp.info/proxies.txt")
    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
    Dim scrapeproxy As String = sr.ReadToEnd
    ListBox2.Items.Add(scrapeproxy)
End Sub
```

For some reason, the ListBox outputs all proxies scraped from http://www.socialstamp.info/proxies.txt in one line, instead of a proxy per line.

Answer (score 1):

Something like;

```
    Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.socialstamp.info/proxies.txt")
    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
    Dim scrapeproxy As String = sr.ReadToEnd

    Dim lstProxyList As New List(Of String)(scrapeproxy.Split(vbLf))

    For Each proxy As String In lstProxyList

        Listbox2.Items.Add(proxy)

    Next
```

Or if you have an `Listbox2.Items.AddRange` (not sure if you're using WPF), then you can use that instead of the loop.